# An identity for generalized q-Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

Let $k$ be a positive integer and consider the generalized $q-$Fibonacci polynomials  $F_n^{(k)}(x)$ which satisfy the recursion $F_n^{(k)}(x) = xF_{n - 1}^{(k)}(x) + q^{n-k} F_{n - k}^{(k)}(x)$ with initial values $F_n^{(k)}(x) = {x^n}$ for $0 \leqslant n < k.$ Denote by $\binom{n}{k}_q$ the $q-$binomial coefficients.
I need the identity
$$\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {{{( - 1)}^{n - 1 - j}}} {x^k}\binom{n-k}{n-j-1}_q
{q^{(k - 1)\left(\binom{n}{2}-\binom{j+1}{2}
\right)}}F_{kj}^{(k)}(x) = {x^n}F_{(k - 1)n}^{(k)}(x).$$
Has anyone an idea for a simple proof?

Comment: You could simplify the LHS by substituting $j' = j+1$

Comment: Do you already have any theorems or lemmata about these generalised $q$-Fibonacci polynomials which might be useful? With subgoal $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} q^{k(n-1)-i} x^i F_{k(n-1)-i}^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{j=k}^{n} (-1)^{n-j} \binom{n+1-k}{j-k}_q q^{(k-1)\left(\frac{(n+1)n - j(j-1)}{2}\right)} F_{k(j-1)}^{(k)}(x)$$ I can see a proof by induction.

Comment: Sorry, I have not stated it explicitly, but my main interest is for $n<k$.

Comment: How are you extending the $q$-binomial coefficients to negative indices?